# Additional Vapor Barrier with Faced Insulation?

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

When installing faced insulation into exterior walls, are there any benefits or detriments to adding an additional vapor barrier to either the non-faced side of the insulation?

Comment: why is this a community wiki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

not 100% certain on this, but a double vapor barrier will actually cause harm as the moisture will have no where to escape to.  Especially if you place it on the non-faced side.  If you place it on the already faced side, it probably wont hurt, but is pointless as you already have the barrier .